# Como retornar código PHP com Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-api

**Tópico editado completamente**

Meu arquivo `Follow_Button.php`:

```
<?php

require_once '.././app/autoload.php';

$TwitterUsers = new TwitterUsers;

require_once '.././app/TwitterOAuthHelper.php';

$helper = new TwitterOAuthHelper;

$row = $TwitterUsers->selectUserAll();
foreach ($row as $fetch) {
    $helper->friend($fetch['id_user']);
}
```

Meu método:

```
public function friend($user_id) {
    $access_token = $_SESSION['twitter_access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

    $friend = $connection->post("friendships/create", [
        "user_id" => $user_id,
        'follow' => true

    ]);

    if ($user_id === $this->signedIn()->id) {
        return false;
    }

    return $friend;

}
```

Queria limitar o código PHP, receber 1 seguidor a cada 10 segundos, e fazer a contagem com `javascript` e ao terminar de executar o código o botão reativar novamente:

```
<a href="" onclick="return getPhpAjax();" class="text-none">
  <button type="button" data-loading-text="Ganhando seguidores..." id="getFollow" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Ganhar seguidores agora
  </button>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getPhpAjax() {
   $.ajax({
      url:'./app/Follow_Button.php',
      complete: function (response) {
         $("#getFollow").click(function() {
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.button('loading');
         });
      },
      error: function () {
          alert('Erro');
      }
  });  

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Utiliza o ajax do jQueey

Comment: Estou tentando... vou atualizar o tópico em breve...

Comment: Atualizado.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deveria zerar o botão e só depois do retorno do PHP que ele deveria ficar novamente disponível.

Tente assim:

```
<a href="" onclick="getPhpAjax();" class="text-none">
  <button type="button" data-loading-text="Ganhando seguidores..." id="getFollow" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Ganhar seguidores agora
  </button>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function enableBtn(state) {

   if(state) { $('#getFollow').text('Loading...').attr('disabled', true) }
   else { $('#getFollow').text('texto original'). attr('disabled', false) }
  }

  function getPhpAjax() {
   enableBtn(false)
   $.ajax({
      url:'./app/Follow_Button.php',
      complete: function (response) {
         var t = setTimeout(function() { enableBtn(true); clearTimeout(t); }, 10000)
      },
      error: function () {
          alert('Erro');
      }
  });  

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Óbvio que é uma definição bem simplória porque você poderia simplesmente remover o código e ele pararia de ficar bloqueado, eu aconselho você fazer um tratamento no servidor para não receber requests antes de 10s

Comment: Funcinou, só tive que alterar a linha `else { $('#getFollow').text('Ganhando seguidores...'). attr('disabled', true) }`... vou marcar como resolvido... mas tenho outra dúvida. como fazer a contagem de seguidores recebidos?

Comment: Ai teria que vir na sua resposta do back end

Comment: Tipo fazer uma verificação, se tanto seguidores for recebido, mas queria contar tipo, você esta recebendo 1,2,3 ... seguidores fazer contagem em tempo real...

Comment: Mas ai muda um pouco a estrutura do seu código, você precisaria abrir um socket para poder fazer isso em tempo real

Comment: com ajax não tem como?, tenho um site aqui de exemplo não sei se pode publicar aqui.

Comment: Eu acho melhor você abrir uma outra pergunta pra isso...

Comment: Ok, vou ir de viagem agora, chegando eu abro...